# How to find out what blacklists my storage device

Tags: usb, external-hdd

I tried to find a solution the whole day until now 3am. I'm cooked.

I am running Ubuntu on a Raspberry Pi with USB 3 and connected to it some external storage enclosures via a USB hub. One of them is controlled by JMicron controller. `lsusb`

```
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 152d:0567 JMicron Technology Corp. / JMicron USA Technology Corp. JMS567 SATA 6Gb/s bridge
```

In the `dmesg` I can see it is blacklisted for some reason.

```
[    2.134591] usb 2-2.1: new SuperSpeed Gen 1 USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
[    2.155251] usb 2-2.1: New USB device found, idVendor=152d, idProduct=0567, bcdDevice= 2.05
[    2.155259] usb 2-2.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=10, Product=11, SerialNumber=5
[    2.155264] usb 2-2.1: Product: USB to ATA/ATAPI Bridge
[    2.155268] usb 2-2.1: Manufacturer: JMicron
[    2.155272] usb 2-2.1: SerialNumber: 152D00539000
[    2.169663] usb-storage 2-2.1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[    2.169914] usb-storage 2-2.1:1.0: Quirks match for vid 152d pid 0567: 5000000
[    2.169997] scsi host0: usb-storage 2-2.1:1.0
[    2.170329] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
[    2.173030] usbcore: registered new interface driver uas
```

It says registered for the interface driver uas.

However it is not used. I believe because of the Quirks. `lsmod` gives

```
uas                    28672  0
usb_storage            81920  6 uas
```

I read it this way. 6 uas capable devices use usb_storage driver instead of uas. I believe this is because of the Quirks (I hate that word).

I tried many things, many of which I do not remember anymore, brain is a pudding.

My goal is to *unblacklist* these devices. **How can I do that?**

Let me know any information you need if you can help and I shall provide.

Comment: How are you determining that the device is blacklisted?

Comment: And how do you know it is not used? USB storage devices are recognized as SCSI disks on Linux; what does `lsblk` tell you, and `dmesg | grep sd`?

Comment: @larsks The line `[    2.169914] usb-storage 2-2.1:1.0: Quirks match for vid 152d pid 0567: 5000000` means a match was found for a quirks, which afaik means that somehow it is blacklisted.

Comment: @berndbausch in my post I list modules (amongst them drivers). uas does not show usage, but usb_storage does. `lsblk` shows the disk property and I can use it, but only with limited speed. Regarding dmesg and sd: I see the devices are used with the scsi interface. That is not my problem. My problem is that usb_storage driver is used instead of uas, which can be translated to: the system uses usb 2 instead of usb 3 - that is my problem. This can popularly happen on a raspberry pi unfortunately.

Comment: From what I read this is done to protect you.  You might like to read the overview here https://www.smartmontools.org/wiki/SAT-with-UAS-Linux if I read that right the kernel is disabling it because it thinks the chipset is functionally broken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JMicron JMS567 does not work properly, at least does it not operate as expected. So do not expect anything to get better, when enabling `uas` for that device.

[Quirks](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/nvme/feature-and-quirk-policy.html#quirks) are workarounds for firmware implementation bugs and a "quirk" was added for the JMS567 quite a while [ago](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/734016b00b50a3c6a0e1fc1b7b217e783f5123a1).

According to the [Kernel parameter documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/kernel-parameters.html) a quirk can be disabled by setting an empty quirk.

Quoting the the [usbcore.quirks documentation](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/78b421b6a7c6dbb6a213877c742af52330f5026d/Documentation/admin-guide/kernel-parameters.txt#LL6608C2-L6608C16):

```
usbcore.quirks=
        [USB] A list of quirk entries to augment the built-in
        usb core quirk list. List entries are separated by
        commas. Each entry has the form
        VendorID:ProductID:Flags. The IDs are 4-digit hex
        numbers and Flags is a set of letters. Each letter
        will change the built-in quirk; setting it if it is
        clear and clearing it if it is set. [...]
```

Please note, that this is from the `usbcore.quirks` documentation, the [usb-storage.quirks](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/78b421b6a7c6dbb6a213877c742af52330f5026d/Documentation/admin-guide/kernel-parameters.txt#LL6681C21-L6681C21) does not mention "setting it if it is clear and clearing it if it is set."

Anyway, to *unblacklist* the device, the following *should* work:

```shellsession
% sudo rmmod uas usb-storage
% sudo modprobe usb-storage quirks=152d:0567:
% sudo modprobe uas
```

To verify that the module parameter has been set:

```shellsession
% cat /sys/module/usb_storage/parameters/quirks
152d:0567:
```

To make the change permanent (aka the module parameter should be automatically set on boot):

```shellsession
% echo "options usb-storage quirks=152d:0567:" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/usb-storage-unblacklist.conf
% sudo update-initramfs -u -k all
```

This should work if the kernel loads `usb_storage` as a module, if it is built in, take a look here to get a hint what to do: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/441772/144250